# What is this symbol in the WebStorm Hide shortcut

Tags: ide, webstorm

What is the symbol next to the shift sign ?

Alt click doesn't do anything either.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's `Escape` .. so the whole shortcut is <kbd>Shift + Escape</kbd>.

Some links:

- http://osxdaily.com/2010/11/07/mac-keyboard-symbols/
- http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200808/mac_keyboard_symbols.html